# How to create a textbox bound to an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I used Entity Framework to generate my controller and view for my class.

This is what I have:

`DemandeController.cs` (controller):

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Demande model = new Demande();
        model.date = DateTime.Now;
        model.status = "en cours";

        Employe emp = (Employe)Session["currentUser"];
        model.Employe = emp;

        ViewBag.ServiceID = new SelectList(db.Services, "id", "nom");
        ViewBag.EmployeID = new SelectList(db.Employes, "matricule", "nom");
        return View(model);
    }
```

Demande -> `Create.cshtml` (View)

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeID, "Employe")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("EmployeID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeID)
    </div>
```

`Employe` class:

```
public partial class Employe
{
    public Employe()
    {
        this.ActivityLogs = new HashSet<ActivityLog>();
        this.Demandes = new HashSet<Demande>();
    }

    public int matricule { get; set; }
    public int DepartementID { get; set; }
    public string nom { get; set; }
    public string prenom { get; set; }
    public string telephone { get; set; }
    public string adresse { get; set; }
    public string fonction { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> isAdmin { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ActivityLog> ActivityLogs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Demande> Demandes { get; set; }
    public virtual Departement Departement { get; set; }
}
```

`Demande` class:

```
public partial class Demande
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeID { get; set; }
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string details { get; set; }

    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
    public virtual Employe Employe { get; set; }
}
```

By default, because I have many employees, the view generates a `dropdownlist` where I have to chose the employe name. That works without problems.

However, I am trying to change the `dropdownlist` into a `textbox` that would display the currently logged-in employe which is saved in a `session` object.

I tried a lot of things such as saving the `Employe` object in the model from the Controller like you can see in the Controller code above but it did not work as the View does not save the entire object to my understanding so when I submit, it overrides the `Employe` object and only leaves the name attribute. It worked for the `date` and `status` because they are basic objects but not for `Employe`.

I tried explaining to the best of capacity, I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC. If there is any further information you'd like me to provide, just let me know.

Comment: What would happen if you changed: @Html.DropDownList("EmployeID", String.Empty) to @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployeID)

Comment: it displays the ID instead of the name and when I submit, it does not work.

Comment: Use a view model for your create view. Have a property called `CurrentUserName` and populate the value of that in your GET action (you can read the value from session and set this property value in your GET action)

Comment: @Shyju can you show me how to make it work? I still struggle with concepts.

Comment: Where is the name you want in the textbox stored ? How ?

Comment: Also your `Demande` class has a `EmployeID` property. So your HttpPost action method needs the EmployID value to do the save/update operation. How are planning to get that Id value if you are planning to replace it in the UI with the name (where users can change it because it is a textbox) ?

Comment: I want the property `nom`from `Employe` class to be displayed in the textbox while the model saves the Employe object which I retrieve from the session.
Also, isn't the Èmploye` object stored in the model supposed to have the ID in it? it worked just fine with the dropdownlist.